# Google Datalab: Java not installed

Tags: java, python, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to utilize the H2O package in a Jupyter notebook running in the Google Datalab hosted on GCP and am getting the error that Java isn’t installed.   I’ve searched the documentation but haven’t found any solutions.  Appreciate any ideas.   Thanks

Comment: It’s google cloud where the problem rests I believe.    Not running Jupyter locally.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the error and any stack trace.

Comment: H2OStartupError: Cannot fund Java.   Please install the latest JRE from....       the problem is that I am running this in Google cloud so I don’t know how to install Java there.   Couldn’t find any documentation for this either.    Thanks.

Comment: That should read cannot find Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is not installed in the Datalab Docker container.  You'll either need to install it after startup or create a custom Docker container using the Datalab one as a base image, as in Option 3 here: https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries